# Deletar uma linha no DBGrid sem apagar no Banco de Dados

Tags: delphi, delphi-10, delphi-berlin, delphi-tokyo, delphi-seatle

Teria como apagar uma ou mais linhas de uma determinada *DBGrid* sem deletar o registro do banco de dados?

Eu estava tentando algo assim mais não deu certo.

```
while not DataModuleGeral2.qryAudienciasInicial.Eof do
begin
  if (DM.qryAudienciasDATA_AUDIENCIA.AsDateTime = Date) and
     (DM.qryAudienciasHORA_AUDIENCIA.AsDateTime < Time) then
  begin
     frmTelaPrincipal.dbgAudiencias.SelectedRows.Delete;
  end else
    DataModuleGeral2.qryAudienciasInicial.Next;
end;
```

Utilizo **Firebird 2.5** e Delphi

Comment: Não é possível apagar uma linha do DBGrid dessa forma que está querendo. Uma ideia seria jogar os dados dentro de um StringGrid e manipular através dele.

Comment: Já pensou em por tudo em uma ClientDataSet?

Comment: pode ser uma  boa ideia...

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar o campo Filter da qryAudienciasInicial para esconder os registos que nao quer mostrar ao utilizador

Algo como

```
qryAudienciasInicial.Filter:='(ID<>5) AND (ID<>6)';
qryAudienciasInicial.Filtered:=true;
```

Claro que aqui devia guardar os registos que o user for apagando para fazer este filtro mais dinamico.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode jogar os dados em um TFDMemTable ao invés de trabalhar diretamente na query, então você linka o TFDMemTable na DBGrid. Para excluir os registros que deseja é só remover eles do TFDMemTable e depois da um refresh na grid.